# SwiftUI global var and func at launch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, global-variables, launch

I have this func that parses a json. Then I use the data for that to populate a bunch of UI slot. The problem is it's a big json (if 10.1MB is big) and it takes 5-8 seconds to load. At app launch that's no big deal, but right now it' reprising that data every time.

Right now I just have this mode were each struct view starts with:

```
var results = [ScryfallCard]()

.onApear {
    results = func()
}

func() -> [ScryfallCard]
```

I can't find for the life of me find out how to make a global variable, assign it the `var globleResults = func()` so my app loads all that data upfront and doesn't take 5 second to load each view.

Comment: Take a look at [Asynchronously Load Data from an API in SwiftUI](https://schwiftyui.com/swiftui/asynchronously-load-data-from-an-api-in-swiftui/). Even if you parse a JSON locally, the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your view to update the results, you need to make turn your results `results` into `@State var results: [ScryfallCard] = []`

Then with your function that deals with the JSON, no matter how long it takes to process, it should update the view once the `results = func()` is finished.

Avoid using global variables and aim for creating different components to encapsulate the variables.

You would have something like this

```
class NetworkRequester: ObservableObject {

    @Published var results: [String] = []

    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    func getResults() {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(fileURLWithPath: "path-to-JSON")!)
            .map({ $0.data })
            .decode(type: [ScryfallCard].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    case .finished:
                    break
                }
            }) { newResults in
                self.results = newResults
        }
    }
}
```

The link suggested in the comment is a useful resource to learn more about how to deal with rendering data.

Comment: Both these answers seem to make the assumption that the data might magically change. The card list only changes once a day at most and often months without changes. But whenever I try to make the data "smart" using State stuff, it always takes way yo long to do even simple stuff like tap on a item in a list, show a detailed view. The tapping the back button also takes forever. The big list of cards needs to be loaded upfront and then called as needed.

Comment: Actually different question. Is it possible to save the parsed JSON to disk. And then read the contents of the parsed json back out in the app?

Comment: @Zerafiall A new question -> a new post. These are the SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... figured it out. Kinda janky but it works.

I basically had to start at the top and put `@EnvironmentObject var globalCards : ScryfallData`  inside my ContentView. The at each view add `@ObservedObject var globalCards = ScryfallData()` and pass  `globalCards: globalCards` on to the next View. Then on the last view just use `List(globalCards.parsedResults, id: \.id) { item in` in my list.

My `print("Parsing...") print("Parsing complete")` only spits out that at the first build and then next parses again. (somehow even after I swipe-up-quit the app then launch it again it doesn't spit out the print()statements)